# how to convert payload into a formData

Tags: angular, typescript

is there a way in angular to convert a payload json object in to a formData ?`const formData: FormData = new FormData();` please check my payload code below I have added it

#payload output

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": null,
    "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
    "annualRentProposed": null,
    "annualRentCurrent": null,
    "firmTermRemaining": null,
    "firmTermAdded": null,
    "maxAvailableTerm": null,
    "status": null,
    "capitalContribution": null,
    "parentCloneId": null,
    "accountId": 4,
    "transactionId": 173,
    "dealTypeValues": "{\"id\":0,\"summary\":\"13123\",\"mlasId\":2,\"startDate\":\"2021-10-27\",\"endDate\":\"2021-10-27\",\"rent\":\"2321\",\"cam\":\"312\",\"securityMonitoringMonthly\":\"12312\",\"supportServicesFee\":\"312\",\"estimatedOtherRevenue\":\"12312\",\"descriptionOfOtherRevenue\":\"3123123\",\"totalMonthlyRentAndFees\":15380,\"buildOutCostReimbursement\":\"123123\",\"dealId\":0,\"startDateString\":\"2021-10-27\",\"endDateString\":\"2021-10-27\"}",
    "isReadyForApproval": false
}
```

#payload code

```
const payload = {
        "id": 0,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": null,
        "firmTermRemaining": null,
        "firmTermAdded": null,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "status": null,
        "capitalContribution": null,
        "parentCloneId": null,
        "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
        "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
        "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues),
        "isReadyForApproval": this.isReadyForApproval    
      }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I have no idea how to directly convert it that is why I am asking

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question Sir

Comment: With the instance of your form, have you tried something like: this.form.patchValue(payload) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert object to FormData with mapping object keys:

```
const myObj = {a: 1, b: 2};

const formData = new FormData();

Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
    formData.append(key, myObj[key]);
});
```

Comment: how about the dealTypeValues which is an object inside my object?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with that object Chritoffer? The HTTP protocol, which will transmit this form data message for you has no knowledge of objects, and cannot reconstruct JavaScript objects on the other end of the communication pipe. You might be looking to *serialize* it

Comment: can you check my payload code above  , I have updated it

Comment: Just a quick fyi that the Code of Conduct asks users to not adress people by their gender if it is not relevant to the topic (which on a programming website it never is ;p )

Comment: the original one was that I POST data using the code payload above , but right now the API is change that data must be Form Data

Comment: `forEach` should be used instead of `map`, when you use `map` it should return a value for each item.